# Angular2-jwt, getting empty errors in GET/POST responses when there is no JWT Token

Tags: angular, jwt

I'm implementing the following tutorial in order to get some Angular basics:
http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

And in addition I actually want to use "angular2-jwt" library. But every GET or POST request I send with authHttp is failing with just an empty error in console if there is no JWT saved locally.
"Error: Error in login.component.html caused by:"

There is no "No JWT present or has expired" error text, nothing.
By the way, standard Http Class is working normally. And so is "tokenNotExpired()" method.
Also tried adding

```
'js-base64':'npm:js-base64/base64.js',
'buffer':'@empty'
```

to mapping information of my systemsjs.config.js, but still no result.

Got any ideas what am I doing wrong? :(

Angular 2.1.0 + angular2-jwt 0.1.25

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {MainComponent} from "./main/main.component";
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth.service";
import {AUTH_PROVIDERS} from "angular2-jwt";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MainComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        AUTH_PROVIDERS
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent {

    user: any = {
        login: 'defaultLogin',
        password: 'defaultPassword'
    };
    errorMsg = '';

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService) { }


    login() {
        this.authService.login(this.user.name, this.user.password)
            .subscribe(result => {

            });
    }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Response} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import {AuthHttp} from "angular2-jwt";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService
{
    constructor(private authHttp: AuthHttp)
    {
    }

    login(username: string, password: string)
    {
        return this.authHttp.post('/api/login', JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}))
            .map((response: Response) =>{
                return false;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting something similar - the error was being swallowed and I was getting a very odd exception about Observables not handling rejections. After some debugging in the JWT library I found out that this was being thrown:    obs.error(new AuthHttpError('No JWT present or has expired'));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the default behaviour of **angular2-jwt**

> By default, if there is no valid **JWT** saved, `AuthHttp` will return an
>   **Observable error** with 'Invalid JWT'. If you would like to continue
>   with an unauthenticated request instead, you can set `noJwtError` to
>   `true`.

You should only use `AuthHttp` when you want to do authenticated requests, so on your AuthService you also need to import the `Http` service, something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import { AuthHttp } from "angular2-jwt";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService
{
    constructor(private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp){ }

    login(username: string, password: string){
      //use this.http instead of this.authHttp
      return this.http.post('/api/login', {username: username, password: password})
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return false;
        });
    }
}
```

As said before **Angular2-jwt** checks for a valid JWT token, if by any chances there isn't a valid JWT then it doesn't even do the request.

But if you want to use authHttp for every request you can disable the JWT token validation, by overriding the configs of the provider, on your **app.modute.ts** add it like this:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component";
import {MainComponent} from "./main/main.component";
import {AuthService} from "./services/auth.service";
import { provideAuth } from 'angular2-jwt';

@NgModule({
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MainComponent
    ],
    providers   : [
        AuthService,
        provideAuth({
          noJwtError: true,
        })
    ],
    bootstrap   : [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule
{
}
```

more info [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#sending-authenticated-requests)

### EDIT:

The AuthService with the error handler:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/toPromise";
import { AuthHttp, AuthHttpError } from "angular2-jwt"; //we need to import the AuthHttpError

@Injectable()
export class AuthService
{
    constructor(private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp){ }

    login(username: string, password: string){
      //use this.http instead of this.authHttp
      return this.http.post('/api/login', {username: username, password: password})
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return false;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError); // we had the catch
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof AuthHttpError) {
          //here we will handle JWT errors
          console.log(error)
        } else if (error instanceof Response) {
          const body = error.json() || '';
          const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
          errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        }else {
          errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: "will return an Observable error with 'Invalid JWT'"
Hm, okay, but is there a way to get that **"Invalid JWT"** error text (actually it must be a **"No JWT present or has expired"** text due to my angular2-jwt sources, but it doesn't really matter)? :)
If I add an error processor as a second parameter in login() method from the login.component.ts (`err => console.log(err)`)

I receive an **"Object { stack: "" }"** message in console.

Comment: And if I try to handleError that in my auth.service.ts
(using **handleError** method from [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling)), 
I get just an "Error" message in console from .toString() method called in handleError. What I'm trying to do here is that I want to keep that default noJWT-error but also I want to have an opportunity to process that exactly error in my requests. Because I can imagine a situation when user is supposed to have a JWT but for some reasons it will not at the moment of making a request. 
Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's a different question, but basically you need to change that **handleError** function a bit, I edited my answer take a look at the **handleError** function

Comment: Oh my god, nope, I still can't reach that message. .json() isn't a function because AuthHttpError isn't a Response. It's just a **{ stack: "" }** object. AuthHttpError extends TS Error class, which has 'name' and 'message' properties. `console.log(error.name, error.message)` currently shows me an empty Name and 'Error' Message...

Comment: Oh in that case switch the order of the if's

Comment: No, IF was working correctly, it is the question of what we need to write in that piece of code. Before writing any new comment I try almost everything to solve the problem. And that's why I tested a json() method there. Still all I get is the above-mentioned **'Error'** message with `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to create a new question, your first question was why you were getting AuthError from JWT, you create a new one, asking how to handle Http and JWt on the same handler

Comment: Are there any side or negative effects of setting noJwtError to true?   I have to do this to get Breeze and Auth0 working - https://auth0.com/forum/t/fyi-using-angular2-breeze-and-auth0/4445/3

Comment: @Rodney nop, the only difference is that when the JWT is expired, the app still does a request to the server

Comment: Ok, and my webapi would reject it as invalid, so I guess that is ok (just an unnecessary server call, but not too bad)